# Joomla3 specific article permissions on front end

Tags: articles, extensions, user, joomla-3.5, permissions

What I would like to do is create a basic wiki using Joomla articles and categories. On the front-end when someone creates an article I would like for them to be able to give other registered members permission to edit. Is this possible in any way out of the box or does it require an extension? If so what extensions would you suggest using?

Comment: So you want the author of the article to be able to select only certain users that he desires to enable as additional editors of his article, or all the user that are part of an editor user-group could be involved in editing all wikis articles? Usually the latter happens on wikis where all authorized users can edit wiki posts.

Comment: Essentially they will be able to select a user to give them permission to edit an article and only that article. This is a feature the person I'm making the site for wants. I'm not entirely sure if the joomla permission system can do something this specific. I have looked through numerous extension and thought about possibly scripting something in with php that interacts with the joomla api. Don't want to go through all that though if its not possible to begin with.

Comment: for this you have to go the customization route and develop it - this doesn't exist in the core and I doubt there is an extension already - even hard to find it in any of the ccks by default I think.